# how can I access elements of array from API response

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, php-curl

I am using a food API that returns food data and I am using PHP Curl to get the response, I used json_decode to decode the data and print it in array format and then looped over the data but when I tried to access specific elements it shows this error

> Warning:  Undefined array key "calories" in C:\Users\hp\Downloads\xampp\htdocs\project\addfood.php on line 32

and here is my code

```
`<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/nutrition?query=1%20glass%20of%20skimmed%20milk.%20",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "x-rapidapi-host: calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key: ce19d0164fmsh3d383efc0e85ce5p16dcb1jsnb1a4a3c79541"
  ],
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  foreach ($data as $item){
    echo $item["calories"]," ",
    $item["serving_size_g"]," ",
    $item["protein_g"]," ",
    $item["carbohydrates_total_g"]," ",
    $item["fat_total_g"], "<br>";
  }
}
```

and this the array that I am trying to access some of its elements

> ```
>     array(1) {
>   ["items"]=>
>   array(1) {
>     [0]=>
>     array(12) {
>       ["sugar_g"]=>
>       float(0)
>       ["fiber_g"]=>
>       float(0)
>       ["serving_size_g"]=>
>       float(245)
>       ["sodium_mg"]=>
>       int(129)
>       ["name"]=>
>       string(4) "milk"
>       ["potassium_mg"]=>
>       int(246)
>       ["fat_saturated_g"]=>
>       float(2.9)
>       ["fat_total_g"]=>
>       float(4.7)
>       ["calories"]=>
>       float(125.7)
>       ["cholesterol_mg"]=>
>       int(19)
>       ["protein_g"]=>
>       float(8.6)
>       ["carbohydrates_total_g"]=>
>       float(12)
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: No need for a `foreach` you can just `echo $data['items'][0]['calories'];`. Or, to make it slightly more readable when accessing the data you could do `$data = json_decode($response, true)['items'][0];` and then simply `echo $data['calories'];`

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you're iterating the wrong array, I think the correct one would be:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($data["items"] as $item)
{
    echo $item["calories"] . "<br>";
}
```